# How to calculate relative error when values are close to zero or negative?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, error-function

I'm trying to calculate the relative error of a machine learning model prediction. Normally I'd calculate the relative error this way

$RelError=\left | \frac{y-\hat{y}}{y} \right |$

However, since `y` can be zero or around zero, this formula causes problems. I changed it for the following:

$RelError=2\frac{\left |y-\hat{y} \right |}{\left | y \right |+ \left | \hat{y} \right |}$

Which has the advantage that it's not undetermined at zero nor it spikes around it. But I still have issues considering the error of negative values.

Consider the following scenario:

$y = -1 \\
\hat{y}=5 \\
RelError=2\frac{\left |-1-5 \right |}{\left | 1 \right |+ \left |5 \right |}= 2\frac{\left |-6 \right |}{\left | 6 \right |}=2$

This isn't exactly right for me: the error isn't "twice as much" as the original value of `y`.

And I don't know if that's the idea I want to give.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: @WW1 Fixed. I had the wrong formula

Comment: This has the property that when $y=0$, the relative error is always 2

Comment: @WW1 The property is that the error can't be larger than 2. If $y$ is negative and $\hat{y}$ isn't, the error is 2 as well.

Comment: You say that you want to compute the relative error, but you don't want to use the formula for relative error. What is your goal? Do you just want to take the min of the relative error and some large constant?

Comment: @Joe I'm open to suggestions about the best way to show the error of $\hat{y}$ in terms of how much it deviates from $y$.

Comment: Show to whom? In an academic paper? If so, I would stick to the conventions of the field, which you could determine by looking at similar papers in the journals you're targeting. If it's to some other audience, what are you trying to communicate? If it's the relative error, then I would use that, no matter how large it is, or if it is undefined. If it's any measure of error, and you don't like the relative error, you could consider the absolute error.

Comment: @Joe It's for a capstone project. I'm comparing Fantasy Football scores to predictions from a machine learning model. Scores are real numbers, usually in the range of [0,10] but sometimes they can be negative or as large as 50.

Comment: In that case, I would probably use mean squared error. Was that the error function that you used to choose the parameters for the model? You could also use the coefficient of determination, to show how much of the variance your model explains.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar function for relative error. My definition is
$$f(x,y) := z = \,|x-y|/(|x|+|y|). $$
In the case that $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs, this returns $1$ which is the maximum relative error. The downside is that if $x$ and $y$ have the same sign and are relatively close, then the function returns a value approximately one half of the usual relative error. The fix for that is to use $\,z(2-z)\,$ which is close to $\,2z\,$ if $\,z\,$ is close to zero and so the modified result is now close to
the usual relative error.

A perhaps better function definition is
$$ f(x,y) := |x-y|/\max(|x|,|y|). $$
This is much closer to the usual relative error but
the denominator is modified so that the function is
now symmetric in $\,x\,$ and $\,y.\,$ It is equal
to the usual relative error in half of the cases.